# Swift arc4random_uniform unWorking

Tags: swift, arc4random

I made a variable using arc4random this way:

```
var a = Int(arc4random_uniform(25))
```

I want `a` to be between 0 and 24.

Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it gives a HUGE value with about 20 characters!

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Int(arc4random_uniform(25))` *does* return a number between 0 and 24. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your random number value:

```
var a : Int = arc4random_unifrom(25)
```

Hope this will help you if you are still having problems.

Answer (score -1):

Swift can be a little unpredictable about how it infers variable types.

Try explicitly type casting both the variable a and the constant (25).  I tested this code and it worked fine:

```
    var a:Int = 0

    for var i:Int = 0; i < 1000; i++
    {
        a = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(25)))
        println("a = \(a)")
    }
```